How to identify the "latest version" of the (Browser) Local Storage & enforce it being aplied to other (idle) tabs?

Is anyone aware how to get the the extact hh:mm:ss of an object written to local storage? (which would help me troubleshooting some weird behavior I am facing)

What is the right way to enforce most recent changes made to local storage (e.g. while on Tab A), being applied to / read from an inactive tab (e.g. tab B) or even a tab on idle (Tab C - with memory saver enabled ) as they get active again? (Since it appears they restore to their previous state, which is not neccessarily the latest state of local storage)



For your first question, why not add a date field in the object written to localStorage?

localStorage can only save strings, so if you have a Date object, you need to convert it into a string before saving it. The tabs can share the same localStorage if they are open on the same origin. For example,  if each tab was open on: https://sub.domain.tld they will share the same localStorage but if one of them is open on https://www.domain.tld it will not share the same localStorage with the others.

Post code as a [mcve] (hint: click the brackets button <>).
